# warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, ubuntu, gdb

I get this error (title of this question), when I am attempting to debug C/C++ programs using gdb with Netbeans IDE.

Does anyone know what this means, and how to get rid of the warning?

I am able to debug despite the warning, but I'd still like to make the warning go away.

Relevant details:

1. OS: Ubuntu 9.10
2. gdb: 7.0-ubuntu
3. Netbeans: 6.8.1

Comment: Have you tried running GDB outside of NeatBeans using gdb -q?

Comment: I can only adive to make gdb executed under strace in your case and investigate the output then.
Alias a gdb with something like "strace -f -o $HOME/str.out gdb".
Some theory on sessions stuff you can look [here][1]


  [1]: http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/_The_Controlling-Terminal_and_Pr.html

Comment: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic15797.html https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166965 https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/469005 It's not just you.  Please go see your distribution or upstream for support.

Answer (score 4):

Project > Properties > Run > Console Type > Output Windows

Comment: What if I do not have the option "Output Windows"? I can only choose between "internal terminal", "external terminal" and "standard output" and none of them works... Netbeans 7.0.1 on OpenSUSE Linux

Comment: I don't have a `Run` option, and also can't find anything on Console Type.  (CB v 16.01 on Debian 9.)  ???

Answer (score -1):

Check that your code has in fact been built with debug.  From experience (in Linux) if you don't have any symbols GDB can give this error.