# issue with debugged application output in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am doing my first steps with GDB in TUI mode.

During the debug session I see that each line outputted to console occurs in a single line (in the picture you see `222222` highlighted in red). It is like having an output pane of one single line.

On top of that, each `\n` doesn't cleanup that line so all the strings do overwrite each other making my output very confusing.

Can you help me a bit with this issue or point me to some key command to look for in order to have a clean output?

I also highlighted another area (in the picture `1111111`) because the first string is outputted there and then all other on the frame of the source code window.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always refresh tui screeen every time your program outputs something with Ctrl+L key binding. Or you can temporarily swith to normal mode, step and watch program output and switch back to tui mode (Ctrl+X A). See all key bindings [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys).

Comment: Thanks a lot! With CTRL+L & out TUI mode looks better. Can I ask you one more question? Do you know a way to create an area in GDB screen similar to the VSStudio OUTPUT PANE? I would like an area of the screen dedicated entirely to the console output and at the same time doing my debug/viewing my code.

Comment: I found this and I hope is gonna help
http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_183.html

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature in gdb as OUTPUT PANE. But it is possible to redirect all program output to another terminal with gdb's TTY command: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html#index-tty-127

Comment: Hi Ks1322! Thanks a lot! I did some research since I don't have this /dev/ttyb in Ubuntu. 
#A. I open a new terminal, give "tty" command to return e.g. "/dev/pts/0" #B. In another terminal where I lunch "gdb"and give "tty /dev/pts/0" to see my output in the first terminal: supre cool! Everything seems fine except for this message "warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted". It seems not really affecting my debugging session by the way but I am not sure 100%. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Maby this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346919/warning-gdb-failed-to-set-controlling-terminal-operation-not-permitted ? Maby this warning is Ubuntu specific? I dont observe it on my Fedora 12 system.

Comment: Worth noting that [you can make gdb run `refresh` automatically on every breakpoint hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936744/2550406)