# gdb scripting: execute commands at selected breakpoint

Tags: scripting, gdb, breakpoints

I'd like to predefine some breakpoints in a gdb script and to invoke some special commands at these breakpoints and afterwards to automatically continue the program execution. So, ideally, I'd like to have a gdb script like the following:

```
b someFunction
...
if breakpoint from above reached do:
  print var1
  call someOtherFunction
  continue
done
```

Additionally an unfortunate fact is, that I can't rely on the python interface for using breakpoints, as the gdb version at the server I currently work at is too old!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do specific action when certain breakpoint hits in gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/do-specific-action-when-certain-breakpoint-hits-in-gdb)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should take a look at the `command` command, which enables you to add gdb commands as a breakpoint is hit.  See the [breakpoint command list](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) section of the gdb manual.

For example:

```
break someFunction
commands
print var1
end
```

will, when the breakpoint on `someFunction` is hit, automatically `print var1`.

Comment: Thank You, that was the key! One little additional remark: If You have extensive output by using such a command and do not want it to be stopped everytime it hits the bottom of the terminal (because then gdb will ask "Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit"), just state "set pagination off" in gdb or your script.

Comment: Note this doesn't work in non interactive mode (--batch or MI mode for example) until https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10079 is fixed

Comment: If say I wand to execute same commands for multiple breakpoints, then how to do it? (without copy pasting;)

Comment: Additional remark: begin and end your command list with `silent` and `cont`: `silent` skips the usual output GDB shows on breakpoint hit, `cont` skips breaking into the interactive prompt; continues after playing your command list. Some call this a _tracepoint_ i.e. just trace values of a variable without stopping execution.

Comment: @VramVardanian `commands` takes a list of breakpoint numbers as an argument.  Use `info b` to list the breakpoints.