# Writing Front End for GDB

Tags: user-interface, gdb, frontend

I want to write a GUI based debugger wrapped over GDB. Because, I dont want the program to stop after watch points or break points. Instead, it should redirect the details like filename, line number, new value and stuffs to a file and continue execution.

I am pretty bad at scripting. So, I want some starting point to start developing front end for  GDB. As far as I googled, this link ***http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_211.html*** is not much understandable for a beginner in this activity?

Hopefully, I will get help on development in C/C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For writing a GDB frontend, you indeed want to use the **GDB/MI** protocol but perhaps read [this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html) up-to-date copy instead of the older one you linked to.

### Sample GDB/MI session

(Lightly edited version of [this section](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Simple-Examples.html#GDB_002fMI-Simple-Examples) from the GDB manual)

**Launching GDB with the MI Command Interpreter**

```
$ gdb -q --interpreter=mi2
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
(gdb)
```

**File /bin/true**

```
-file-exec-and-symbols /bin/true
^done
(gdb)
```

**Break main**

```
-break-insert main
^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x00000000004014c0",func="main",file="true.c",fullname="/usr/src/debug/coreutils-8.17/src/true.c",line="59",times="0",original-location="main"}
(gdb)
```

**Run and Breakpoint Hit**

```
-exec-run
=thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="2275"
=thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
^running
*running,thread-id="all"
(gdb) 
=library-loaded,id="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",target-name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",host-name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
=library-loaded,id="/lib64/libc.so.6",target-name="/lib64/libc.so.6",host-name="/lib64/libc.so.6",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
=breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x00000000004014c0",func="main",file="true.c",fullname="/usr/src/debug/coreutils-8.17/src/true.c",line="59",times="1",original-location="main"}
*stopped,reason="breakpoint-hit",disp="keep",bkptno="1",frame={addr="0x00000000004014c0",func="main",args=[{name="argc",value="1"},{name="argv",value="0x7fffffffde98"}],file="true.c",fullname="/usr/src/debug/coreutils-8.17/src/true.c",line="59"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="1"
(gdb)
```

**Continue**

```
-exec-continue
^running
*running,thread-id="1"
(gdb) 
=thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
=thread-group-exited,id="i1",exit-code="0"
*stopped,reason="exited-normally"
```

**Quitting GDB**

```
(gdb) 
-gdb-exit
^exit
```

### Existing GDB/MI Clients

There are several GDB/MI client implementations in C, C++, Java, Python. I'll list a few that I find easy to read:

- The inactive [libmigdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmigdb/) project ([sample program](http://libmigdb.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libmigdb/libmigdb/examples/linux_test.c?view=markup), [public interfaces](http://libmigdb.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libmigdb/libmigdb/src/mi_gdb.h?view=markup#l396)) -- The good news is that it's an attempt at creating a reusable C library. The bad news is that it's not well maintained, e.g. I think it's missing GDB **non-stop** mode and **catchpoint** commands support, features that your use case would likely need.
- [python-gdb-mi](https://bitbucket.org/minami/python-gdb-mi) -- Quite readable if you know Python
- The [C++ GDB/MI client code in QtCreator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/plugins/debugger/gdb/gdbengine.cpp) -- Also quite readable though it's written as part of an abstraction layer to support multiple debugger engines.

You might want to also browse [this list](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends) of GDB frontends.

Comment: OK, how to send commands to gdb from another (GUI) program? Pipes?

Comment: @Mr.Newman, redirect STD{IN,OUT,ERR} to 3 different pipes and execute `gdb --interpreter mi2 --nx`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But what is the main advantage of MI against normal gdb mode?

Comment: Machine parseable async event notifications and command response. GDB/MI is far from perfect, though. I wish we'll get something better in the future.

Comment: please, help one more) when I redirect STDIN to fifo-file my_file and launch 'gdb < my_file' the gdb executes commands from my_file and quits. How can I prevent quiting?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already pointed out the gdb/mi interface maybe an existing solution might give you an idea on how to address your needs. [Here is a list of existing interfaces.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends) Look at their approaches and how they address the different issues.

Another approach that might be helpful could be automated sessions. Not to discourage you from writing a gdb gui, but such an automation could be a good start to get a feeling for the steps needed and could maybe also used as a start. Maybe generating a session script and starting gdb with it. gdb -x to load a command file.

Here a link concerning automating:
[What are the best ways to automate a GDB debugging session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/automating-gdb-sessions)

I hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Though writing new GUI tools gives you more knowledge, I suggest you to take up eclipe and modify according to your needs. It saves lot of your time as well as more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, the environment is an embedded device, and the process I want to debug is tightly coupled with engine. So, running this process on PC is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Programming a gdb wrapper to achieve your goal is way to much work.

See how you can execute script on breakpoint hits: [gdb scripting: execute commands at selected breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935443/gdb-scripting-execute-commands-at-selected-breakpoint)

Also take a look a gdb tracepoints: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html