# C/C++ Linux GDB API

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I want to make me a small GUI version of the `GDB` command line program on `Linux` to make debugging of small `C` programs more easier.  There may exists already some especially in IDEs but I want to make it for fun and get better known to `GDB`.

Now I wanted to know whether GDB has a API so I can access GDB commands directly from code and I don't have to make a detour through the terminal for example with `popen`.

If there does not exists such a API from `GDB`, whats the simplest way to start `GDB` hidden and send commands to it, retrieve outputs from it?

Comment: There is some useful information here about this: https://sourceware.org/gdb/papers/libgdb2/libgdb_toc.html

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid question. It isn't asking for a recommendation at all but for (1) whether there is an api, and (2) an example. And it happens to have a valid answer which was gone and deleted! :( quite sad. This shows up first on google. Even with all arguments, this still serves as an excellent resource.

Comment: Related: [Writing Front End for GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16771393/4975230)

Comment: **Warning:** It looks like the top google result, libgdb, [has been abandoned for years](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2009-03/msg00676.html); It looks like GDB MI is a better option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many IDEs such as Eclipse and KDevelop use GDB MI (Machine Interface). It is line based machine oriented text interface to GDB. See full list here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends.

See these links to get started with GDB MI:

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-cdt-debug2/