# How can I make a GUI for gdb?

Tags: user-interface, gdb

I have to build a gui for gdb , so that I can debug C programs by selecting options in the GUI for gdb .How can I achieve this?(the gdb commands should run at the back end of gui)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ Linux GDB API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921105/c-c-linux-gdb-api)

Comment: Related: [Writing front end for GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771393/writing-front-end-for-gdb)