# Are gdb libraries available for use?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gdb, libraries

gdb has some functionalities that I would like to use in a program. For example tracing a program's system calls and the "list" functionality that shows the source code of a program.

I know that gdb uses both ptrace and the BFD libraries to accomplish these 2 functionalities. However, instead of rewriting already existing code, I am interested in finding libraries and functions that I could use.

Does anyone know if there are gdb libraries that I could use? and if not, are there any other similar debuggers that I could use that might offer these functionalities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ Linux GDB API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921105/c-c-linux-gdb-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there are gdb libraries that I could use?

There are not. There was a proposal to have GDB packaged as a re-usable [libgdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/papers/libgdb2/libgdb.html), but the effort never received much support and has been [completely abandoned](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2009-03/msg00676.html) 7 years ago.

> are there any other similar debuggers that I could use that might offer these functionalities?

The [lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/) follows the general LLVM direction of packaging everything as a library:

```
The LLDB debugger APIs are exposed as a C++ object oriented interface
in a shared library.
```

I have no personal experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore on [libdgb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/papers/libgdb2/libgdb_toc.html). Although I don't know if this being actively pursued.

Comment: No, you should not: it's an abandoned effort from many years ago: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2009-03/msg00676.html