# how to run a program in terminal using c++/python program and then execute statements in that program

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, gdb

I want to create a GUI for GDB debugger, so I need a way to run GDB debugger in terminal and execute commands in that and also get output from that on user triggered events on my screen in ubuntu. how can I do that for such a program?

it tried

```
int main(){
    system("gnome-terminal 'gdb  test'");
    system("break main");
    return 0;
}
```

but it executes the command on the terminal not on the gdb program

Comment: System will not feed gdb input. Pass a gdb script to gdb instead.

Comment: can you give any reference to how to pass 'gdb script' cz i have no idea how to do that or what that realy means

Comment: @kar09 Do you even [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb%20script), bro?

Comment: @kar09 Learn how to use your tools please.

Comment: Related: [writing front end for gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771393/writing-front-end-for-gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the `system()` calls opens a separate shell. So these are independent of each other.

If you want to continuously communicate with a child process, rather use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) please.

Comment: @kar09 Using I/O (file descriptors).  Check the `popen()` examples around on the interwebz. (and read the link I've provided)