# How to generate all backtraces of a function using gdb?

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb, profiling, backtrace

I have a function that I am trying to examine. I want to find all callers of this function, but there are a few issues:

- I am doing this to understand the code because I did not write it, but I need to know exactly how it behaves
- It runs through the STL beforehand, so I can't just use something like `callgrind` to get it's immediate callers

There is a stack trace of 10+ function calls until you get to actual code that is *not* in the STL that caused this function to be invoked. But those STL entry points vary, as it is a `compare` function and calls for `is_equal` go through a different sequence than those that go through `not_equal`, etc. I will need to do this for at least 10+ *different* functions, and I want to streamline this as much as possible.

I want a tool that can dump each unique, **full** backtrace each time the function is called. Does anybody know a tool that can do this?

I am using gdb and c++ on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make gdb execute a series of commands each time a given breakpoint is executed, e.g.,

```
break someFunction
commands
bt
continue
end
```

The feature is mentioned in *[gdb scripting: execute commands at selected breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936744/4518274)*, which has a link to the online documentation for gdb ***[5.1.7 Breakpoint Command Lists](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands)***

Comment: Great answer, I never knew that existed. Thanks!